# Did some part of Voldemort's soul get stuck in Harry Potter's body in Sorcerer's Stone?

Tags: harry-potter, the-philosophers-stone

**Note:** Please answer only without mentioning the sequel movies in the Harry Potter series. I've only watched the first movie. Watched all in my childhood but now I've to watch all again. If it's not possible without mentioning the sequel movies, you can skip it.

---

I was watching Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone again (the last time I watched it in my childhood on TV and didn't have much understanding).

In the end, Voldemort's soul tries to enter Harry's body. I read some articles which say it happened because Voldemort wanted to stick himself to Harry's body as a parasite but failed and he came out of Harry from other end.

Now, immediately after that Harry got terrible pain and he became unconscious. So I don't exactly understand why it happened. Did some soul part get stuck inside Harry that hurt him?

Or would that stuck part hurt him later in life and give some "Voldemort Symptoms"?

Comment: Some things that happened *before* the events of The Philosopher's (or Sorcerer's) stone are not explained until later books or movies. So there can be no satisfactory answer to your question *without* referring to them. Whether this would *spoil* later movies is unclear. But you will have to watch or read the sequels if you want to know why your explanation is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Did some soul part got stuck inside Harry that hurt him?

No, not during the events of *Philosopher's Stone*.

Note that the scene plays out differently in the book. In the book, Harry passes out while he is still struggling with Quirrell, due to an unbearable pain in his scar, and Voldemort's soul makes no attempt to possess him. Harry likely suffered that same unbearable scar pain during Voldemort's possession attempt in the film.

I think this is all I can tell you without spoiling the later films.

Comment: Oh so maybe he fainted because of scar. But the way scene is filmed, it happens like just after Voldemort passes through him, it causes him pain and he is fainted.

Comment: Yep, Voldemort passing through him would have been what caused the scar pain. Again, I'm not sure I can explain why without spoiling the later films.

Comment: This is so hard to answer...the scar pain itself has a story and saying anything about it reveals future plot.

Comment: @F1Krazy @ rtaft oh you meant the original scar on his forhead? I thought some other wound.

Comment: If yes, that makes better sense.